# Removing a div with no id or class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My wordpress blog is having issues with *syntax highlighter evolved* plugin, and there's this weird div element popping out:

```
<div style="z-index: -1; position:absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 4031px;"></div>
```

This causes my page to extend, creating a big space at the end of the page. This also is found on every wordpress blog. Funny thing is, only chrome sees that (using Inspect Element). I've already tried in IE9 developer tools and FF firebug, the div is not there and my page is fine.

**NOTE**: I've already posted a separate question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/wheres-did-this-div-element-come-from). And my question here is different from that.

I want to fix this little problem so bad, and it just came to my mind to use JavaScript for this. What I want to do is: **Remove the div with javascript**.

It's easy removing a div with an ID or class, but this one doesn't have any. I also do not want to affect all the other divs. How can I accomplish this?

**P.S.** It has no parent IDs or class. It's right after the container class div. It's parent is `<body>`.

**EDIT**: Here's the html:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some context to it? Do any parent elements have an `id`. Is it in a unique nesting level, i.e. no other `div` siblings?

Comment: Are you sure that the tag attributes are in the text-node (ie: between the start and end tag)?

Comment: @alex It has no parent IDs or class. It's right after the container class div. It's parent is `<body>`.

Comment: Note that your screenshot shows a div with the attributes in the correct place, *not* as text. Your quoted code at the top of your question shows the attributes as content *within* the div. Is that a typo?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder typo, sorry.. Can't copy directly from chrome element inspector. :)

Comment: @Ruel: *"Can't copy directly from chrome element inspector"* That's odd, I can (right click the element, choose "Copy as HTML"). But no worries, if the style properties really are style properties I can rely on them in my answer (and I have).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder woops, I didn't right click earlier, lol. I tried double clicking. xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's always last or close to last you can use jQuery or normal CSS3 selectors

```
$('body > div:last-child').remove();
```

OR

```
$('body > div:nth-last-child(n)').remove();
```

More on [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos) and [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

OR  you could use CSS i.e.

```
body > div:last-child (or div:nth-last-child(n)) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: My bad, this worked. Had to disable light-box though (because of extra divs), but its not essential. Solved, thanks!

Comment: `@Ruel` use `nth-last-child(3)` (or 2, I'm not sure)! It will count back 2 from the last div so you can use the lightbox. Just make sure if you disable the lightbox that you change this! :P

Comment: @Ruel: Note that `last-child` in CSS is not supported by IE prior to IE9, which hasn't been released yet. (I assume it's the CSS part of this you liked, since you said in response to [Nitin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253431/removing-a-div-with-no-id-or-class-with-javascript/4253456#4253456) that you didn't want to use jQuery.) IE CSS compatibility chart: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, actually it's only chrome generating that div. It's also here in SO, (check inspector). Besides, it's only chrome giving me the headache earlier. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, You can reference the div using a parent or sibling div that might have an ID or class defined.

For examample :

```
<div id="parentDIVID">

  <div>your problem div</div>

</div>


Then you can use jQuery to reference your problem div like this : $("#parentDIVID > div")
```

If you can provide more html code surrounding your problem div, we can construct a jQuery selector that will work in your case.

**Update : Based on the markup provided**

```
function removeDiv() {

    var parent = document.getElementById("stimuli_overlay").parentNode;

    var children = document.getElementById("stimuli_overlay").parentNode.childNodes;

    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

        if (children[i].style.zIndex == -1)
            parent.removeChild(children[i]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not wish to use jQuery, and its parent is `<body>`.

Comment: @Ruel : This can be achieved with straight javascript code too, but for that we need more context regarding the HTML code surrounding your problem div.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the html, (can't copy directly from chrome).

Comment: @Rule: Try the code i posted above in the update. it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (els[i].innerHTML == 'style....') {
    els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You *could* do that, but it makes the browser work really hard (spinning through the DOM tree to build the HTML string for `innerHTML`). And of course, his target div may well be within another div.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Based on the fact that you can't rely on the div used below.

If the div really is the **always the last div** in the document, this is actually easier:

```
var divs, div;
divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
if (divs.length > 0) {
    div = divs.item(divs.length - 1);
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/osari3)

`length - 1` will remove the last div in the document. If you needed to skip a lightbox div or something, adjust to use `- 2` or `- 3`, etc.

**Old Answer** using the earlier information:

<s>Given that structure, something along these lines:</s>

```
// Get the div that follows it, which conveniently has an ID
var div = document.getElementById('stimuli_overlay');

// If that worked...
if (div) {
    // ...move to the previous div, with a bit of paranoia about blank non-element
    // nodes in-between
    div = div.previousSibling;
    while (div && (div.nodeType !== 1 || div.tagName !== "DIV")) {
        div = div.previousSibling;
    }

    // Check that this really is the right div
    if (div && div.tagName === "DIV"
        // The following checks look for some of the style properties that your
        // screenshot shows are set on the div
        && div.style.position == "absolute"
        && div.style.zIndex == "-1"
        && div.style.top == "0px"
        && div.style.left == "0px"
        && div.style.width == "100%"
        && /* ...possibly more checks here... */) {
        // Remove it
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but those divs are generated so they appear in random order, and I disabled lighbox plugin (to remove those generated divs), for the accepted solution to work.