# Remove div element with no id

Tags: javascript, html

How can I find `<div>` tags with no id?

This is my markup:

```
<body>
    <div>this is a text</div>
</body>
```

This is my JavaScript used to add `div`s to the page:

```
var show = function () {
    var htmlNode = document.createElement('DIV');
    document.body.insertBefore(htmlNode, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    htmlNode.innerHTML = 'this is a text';
 };

 if (window.addEventListener) {
     window.addEventListener("load", show, true);
 } else {

 }        

 window.attachEvent("onload", show);
```

How can I remove this after the page is loaded? By putting the JavaScript in the bottom of the page?

Comment: you can override the show() function to do nothing.

Comment: You add the DIV on page load. When do you want to remove it?

Comment: May you check previous questions? [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253431/removing-a-div-with-no-id-or-class-with-javascript)?

Comment: If im honest, I think all he wants to do is show a div that says 'loading' and then remove it when the page is finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the `htmlNode` handle, you already have a route to remove the element.

```
document.body.removeChild(htmlNode);
```

You just need the `htmlNode` variable to be in a scope shared by the `show` function and the function your write to remove it:

```
var htmlNode;

var show = function () {
    htmlNode = document.createElement('DIV');
    document.body.insertBefore(htmlNode, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    htmlNode.innerHTML = 'this is a text';
};

var hide = function () {
    document.body.removeChild(htmlNode);
};
```

Alternatively, you can give it an id...

```
htmlNode = document.createElement('DIV');
htmlNode.id = 'MyElementId';
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$('DIV:not([id])').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove just this one DIV, or any without IDs?

If you're trying to remove all DIVs without IDs, use getElementsByTagName('div') to retrieve all DIVs, iterate through them and check the for the absence of the ID attribute.

Comment: the div has no id, i said that in the post.

Comment: @agh: Is there some reason you won't give it an ID?

Comment: I have no control over it being outputted to the page, that's way

Comment: I understood there's no ID, so you have to use other information to locate and eliminate the DIV. getElementsByTagName('div') will read All divs, allowing you to check for ID, and if its not found, eliminate it. other answers here use the position - just after body - to locate it.

Answer (score -1):

`document.body.childNodes[0].removeChild();`

Comment: provided, there is nothing after body